# Parameters vs JSON strings while designing an API with Rails for use with AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building an API to receive POST data and return JSON in Ruby on Rails 3. I am submitting the data using the angularjs $http object.

```
var post_data = {
    content: $scope.post_content,
    authentication_token: csrf
};

$http({
    url: feed_endpoint,
    method: "POST",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    params: post_data
    }).success(function(post_data, status, headers, config) {

    }).error(function(post_data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
}
```

The escaping of quotes etc. works well with this method where I was having issues with the JSON being created incorrectly while just passing a js data object(hash) to the $http.data object.

I am looking for input on the merits of doing it either way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $http.post, this form works for me.

```
$http.post(feed_endpoint, post_data, {"Authorization": ""})
    .success(function(response) {...}
```